# Non-toxic alternative to borax for use in slime chemistry?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, proteins

I understand that sodium tetraborate decahydrate ($\ce{Na2B4O7•10H2O}$) and water is the primary binder for PVA glue based slimes.

We have learned borax is not good for the ground water, or marine life, so I am trying to determine if there is a safer alternative substance that would produce the same cross-linking effect between the protein molecules of the glue and the borate ions $\ce{(B(OH)4)}$ of the borax solution. The hope is a non-newtonian fluid.

If not, is there something that could be added to the slime, to neutralize the borax, making it safely compostable?

Comment: @Shannon Strong. What is the nature of the glue used for making PVA Glue based slime ? Is it a protein ?

Comment: Exactly what do you think is toxic about borates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boron's toxicity depends on how much you're making, and how you would dispose of it.

There's *some* naturally-occurring boron in the environment, and boron is a necessary for many green plants. Borax is commercially available for home laundry use. This [Safety Data Sheet](https://www.mnclay.com/msds/pdf/chem_raw/boraxg.pdf) states it is, "Readily degradable in the environment."

Therefore, if you're using no more than the quantity used in home-laundry, and if the waste is sufficiently diluted, then disposal through community sewage is reasonable. Since the slime is *so* thick, sufficient dilution is almost *inevitable* to get it down the drain.